# javascript function - variables passed into function work for IE, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript

below is a java script function and the html for the clicked item that calls this function. I was able to tell by using alerts that the four values passed into the function are undefined when using firefox, but work when using IE. Please let me know if anyone sees the mistake and how to pass these values in correctly. Thank you.

```
            function LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, FullExpand, EquipID) {

            document.getElementById('dropTypes').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('dropTypes').style.background = "white";
            DescStatus = 0;

            alert('lnEntityCat : ' + lnEntityCat);
            if (lnEntityCat == 0) {

                alert('First if is hit');
                PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0, 0, 1, LoadChildCallback);

            }
            else if (document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).canExpand == "true") {
                if (document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).src = "../images/minus.gif"

                    PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0, 0, 1, LoadChildCallback);

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).src = "../images/plus.gif"
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the dynamic html which is generated by server side code which generates the item which when clicked,calls loadChild

```
<img canExpand="true" style="cursor:hand" id="img72635" src="../images/plus.gif" EntityID="726" EntityCat="35" onclick="LoadChild(this.EntityID, this.EntityCat, 0, this.lnEquip);">
```

Comment: Considering that for three out of four of the parameters you're attempting to use attributes of the element, why not just pass a reference to the element instead and get the values out inside the function? Makes the code easier to extend if you need to add attributes, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying on non-standard attributes on the element being reflected as properties on the element object. You can't reliably, um, rely on that; you need to use `getAttribute` instead:

```
onclick="LoadChild(this.getAttribute('EntityID'), this.getAttribute('EntityCat'), 0, this.getAttribute('lnEquip'));">
```

(Not quite sure where `lnEquip` was coming from, I don't see it in the attributes on the element; if you're adding it as an expando elsewhere, then remove the `getAttribute` call from that particular one.)

---

Note that using non-standard attributes means your HTML will not [validate](http://validator.w3.org). You can do this in a conforming way, now, by prefixing those attributes with `data-` as described in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). Though that remains invalid in HTML4 and earlier, it works in all browsers, and becomes valid as of HTML5.

Comment: thank you, the getAttribute is what I was looking for. Sorry - newer to javascript and converting old legacy code to code that works in other browsers. Thanks again.

Comment: @njj56: Glad that helped! Best,